# Generate different pdf for each row in a datatable

Tags: asp.net

I need to have a functionality that on click of a button i need to generate pdf file for each record in the datatable.

I require to generate report card and then mail that report card to each person. the data for report card is fetched into a datatable for all students.

I just need a functionality that i can generate individual pdf from datatable.

Thanks

Comment: What have you achieved so far? Where does your problem lie? PDF generation or data access? Currently your question is along the lines of asking people to design an entire solution for your problem.

Comment: I have created the HTML from each row and loop through that. i just want to know how to save each pdf to a perticular location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a page [here](http://www.aspnetworld.com/articles/2004011801.aspx) that covers various solutions to creating PDF documents on the fly. One of particular note to you looks to be the [ASP.NET FO PDF Report Server Control](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npdf/) which can generate PDF files directly from a DataTable. It looks rather old but might suffice.

One additional tip is you will want to look at [Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) solutions too, so that you are not always generating a new PDF every time the button is clicked, unless you specifically want that to happen (for instance if the server-load won't be that high and/or the data is changing frequently, though it doesn't sound like it is).